# Why offsetParent is still showing body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, offset

So I was reading a book, and find out **offsetParent** can't have a **static position**.

So I tried to implement this by writing custom code:

HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="position: static;">
    <div id="div" style="position: static;">
        <h1 id="hi">hi</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I **tested in console** I found out:

```
console.log(div.offsetParent, h1.offsetParent);  // BODY TAG
```

Why?

Comment: Why do you ask something like this here, instead of simply going and _reading up_ on how this works, on your own …? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent

Comment: But I have set body position as Static. Thus it should not be consider any offsetParent ? Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, and because you have set the body to static, this part applies: _“If there is no positioned ancestor element, the nearest ancestor td, th, table will be returned, or the body if there are no ancestor table elements either.”_

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) (emphasis mine):

> The HTMLElement.offsetParent read-only property returns a reference to the element which is the closest (nearest in the containment hierarchy) **positioned** ancestor element.

I.e. In your case, the `BODY` element is the closest *positioned* element for both the `DIV` and the `H1`.  If you want the immediate parent element, use `parentElement` instead.

(FWIW, the main reason for using `offsetParent` is to identify which parent element's coordinate system `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` are relative to.)

Comment: But I have set body position as Static. Thus it should not be consider any offsetParent ? Isn't it ?